# Leaflet clear geojson layer (polyline)

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am a creating a polyline using a geojson. The format of my geojson is as below:

```
var myLines = [{
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[-75, 21.9], [-75.4, 22.7], [-76.5, 23.4]]
    }, {
    "type": "LineString",
     "coordinates": [[-105, 40], [-110, 45], [-115, 55]]
}];

        L.geoJson(myLines).addTo(map);
```

I have a clear polyline function as below:

```
function clear_polyline(){
$.each(myLines, function(ind,poly){
map.removeLayer(poly);
});
}
```

This function does not clear the layer nor does it throw any error.
How do I clear a polyline in leaflet?

Answer (score 13):

You need to remove the Leaflet layer from the map, not the GeoJSON object that the layer was created from.  L.GeoJSON is a FeatureLayer that will contain all of the items in "myLines" so you should do something like this to remove it:

```
var linesFeatureLayer = L.geoJson(myLines);
linesFeatureLayer.addTo(map);

function clear_polyline() {
  map.removeLayer( linesFeatureLayer );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var linesFeatureLayer = L.geoJson(myLines);
linesFeatureLayer.clearlayer()
```

Comment: i think it should rather read: `linesFeatureLayer.clearLayers()`

Comment: `clearLayers is not a function` this method does not work on `L.geoJSON`